# Удалить элемент ассоциативного массива по ключу?

Tags: php, массивы

Есть большой двух уровненный массив, первый ключ число, второй строка, кирилица, и есть файл со списком ключей которые нужно удалить.
Как можно удалить нужные ключи из этого массива?

как пробовал делать:

```
$file3=file("ignore.txt");

print_r($sparam2[0]);
print_r($sparam2[2]);

for ($i = 0; $i <count($sparam2); $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j <count($file3); $j++) {
    $keys4=$file3[$j];
    echo $sparam2[$i][$keys4]."<br>";
    unset($sparam2[$i][$keys4]);    
    }
}
```

прикол в том, что даже строка echo $sparam2[$i][$keys4]."
"; ничего не выводит, echo  $keys4 выводит нужный ключ.

вот результат вывода элементов (пример массива)

print_r($sparam2[0]);
 print_r($sparam2[2]);

```
Array
(
    [Название] => Название
    [Код Русского Света] => Код Русского Света
    [Артикул] => Артикул
    [Бренд] => Бренд
    [Цена] => Цена
    [Длина] => Длина
    [Источник света] => Источник света
    [Исполнение] => Исполнение
    [Аккумуляторный] => Аккумуляторный
    [Материал] => Материал
    [Тип батареи] => Тип батареи
    [Водонепроницаемый] => Водонепроницаемый
    [Цвет корпуса] => Цвет корпуса
    [Наличие на складе] => Наличие на складе
    [Ширина] => Ширина
    [Высота] => Высота
    [Тип светильника] => Тип светильника
    [Способ монтажа] => Способ монтажа
    [Тип цоколя] => Тип цоколя
    [Мощность лампы] => Мощность лампы
    [Класс защиты от поражения электрическим током] => Класс защиты от поражения электрическим током
    [Материал корпуса] => Материал корпуса
)
Array
(
    [Название] => Фонарь S-LD043-B Silver Uniel UL-00000191
    [Код Русского Света] => 413391
    [Артикул] => UL-00000191
    [Бренд] => Uniel 
    [Цена] => 116.82
    [Длина] => 88 мм
    [Источник света] => Светодиод
    [Исполнение] => Карманный фонарь цилиндрической формы
    [Аккумуляторный] => Нет
    [Материал] => Алюминий
    [Тип батареи] => Мизинчиковый
    [Водонепроницаемый] => Да
    [Цвет корпуса] => Серебристый
    [Наличие на складе] => Штука
    [Ширина] => 
    [Высота] => 
    [Тип светильника] => 
    [Способ монтажа] => 
    [Тип цоколя] => 
    [Мощность лампы] => 
    [Класс защиты от поражения электрическим током] => 
    [Материал корпуса] => 
)
```

Для примера в файле игнора два ключа 
Материал
Тип батареи

Их нужно исключить из этого массива.

Comment: мне нужно проверять не значения, а сам ключ

Comment: В данном случае это не имеет значения. У вас та же ошибка и ответ на ваш вопрос такой же.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Немного не правильно. Как вы можете удалять елемент из массива и динамически проверять его размер?
Нужный код должен быть примерно такой (если конечно данные из файла валидные, а то вы file используете без параметров...):

```
$file3=file("ignore.txt");

print_r($sparam2[0]);
print_r($sparam2[2]); // индекс 2 ??? это не ошибка?

$nof_params = count($sparam2);
$file3_count = count($file3);
$array_to_delete = array(); //создаем массив елементов для удаления

for ($i = 0; $i <$nof_params; $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j <$file3_count; $j++) {
    $keys4=$file3[$j];
    echo $sparam2[$i][$keys4]."<br>";
    array_push($array_to_delete, array($i, trim($keys4)));
    }
}

for($i = 0; $i < count($array_to_delete); $i++)
{
    $ii = $array_to_delete[$i][0];
    $keys4 = $array_to_delete[$i][1];
    unset($sparam2[$ii][$keys4]); 
}
```

Comment: по поводу >индекс 2 не ошибка, просто 0 и 1 элемент идентичны, добавил второй парметр для file и попробовал Ваш код, результат к сожалению не изменился...

Comment: А если так:
в ответе изменил строчку array_push($array_to_delete, array($i, trim($keys4)));

Comment: Супер!!! Спасибо! Большое! То что нужно сейчас начал работать!!! Блин откуда там пробел взялся.....

Comment: Это из-за использования функции file() без дополнительных параметров :)

Answer (score 1):

Неоднократно уже поднимались тут вопросы связанные с функцией [file()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file.php). Если ее используют без настройки вторым параметром, получают не то, что хотели.

```
$file3 = file("ignore.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
```

где

```
FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES - Не добавлять новую строку к концу каждого элемента массива 
FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES - Пропускать пустые строки
```

Comment: к сожалению не помогло...